# Goto statement with condition in C

Tags: c, goto

How to do goto statement with if and else condition
i want from my user to make a decision if he/she wants to startover or not

```
 loop1 :
        printf("how many dagre entering ? \n");
        scanf("%d", &NumOfGrade);

        for ( i = 0 ; i < NumOfGrade ; i ++ ) {

            printf("\nenter the grade\n");
            scanf("%d", &grade);

            totalGrade += grade ;

            if ( grade < 12 )
            failsCount ++;
        }

        ave = (float) totalGrade / NumOfGrade ;

        printf("the ave of ur grade are  : \n");
        printf("%.2f\n", ave);
        printf("%d subj fails\n", failsCount);

        printf("do you want to startover ? (Y or N) \n");
        ans = getchar();
        if ( ans == 'Y') 
            goto loop1 ;
```

It's not going to loop1, and i cant see why.

Comment: Or you could use a loop construct. Like, oh I don't know, `do...while`?

Comment: The goto with an if  is fine. So ans must not be what you think it is. Print it out. Maybe it's as simple as case.

Comment: There are situations when using labels and `goto` is okay. Instead of a loop is not one of those situations.

Comment: Also remember that there is a difference between upper and lower case letters. `'Y' != 'y'`.

Comment: @StoryTeller - people reflexively say "remove goto" when actually the programs are perfectly well structured. They hear "do ... while good goto bad" without actually understanding what a structured program is. It is not "one with no gotos".

Comment: Your code is not complete!

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean, I like `goto`s, they can make resource management a lot cleaner in the face of errors, or tidy up a jump from a nested loop. It's not without it's uses, but replacing a loop is not one of them. It makes the code *less* readable.

Comment: @user3121023 i used the scanf without space and with space and its worked with space , why ?

Comment: The `getchar()` gets fed with the new-line you entered to complete the previous `scanf()`.

Comment: @user3121023 thanks , its worked :)

Comment: @StoryTeller the if else statement in this project makes my code more readable , but do while is ok too , thanks

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean i printed and you was right , the getchar didnt take care from input and i did it with scanf , why getchar didnt worked ?

Comment: @wizardofoz, the jump to a label with a meaningless name does not make you code more readable.

Comment: @StoryTeller good point y friend , thanks

Comment: @wizardofoz if you print out the *numerical* value of `ans` you will see that you read the `newline` which was left in the input buffer after the previous `scanf`. Adding the space in front of `" %c"` directs the code to ignore leading whitespace. As commented before you asked!

Comment: @WeatherVane i see , and how i can use getchar in situation like this

Comment: Like this: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` but is better not to mix & match different input methods. Look how much more elegant is `scanf(" %c", &ch);`

Answer (score 0):

you did't clear input buffer, try this:

```
loop1 :
    printf("how many dagre entering ? \n");
    scanf("%d", &NumOfGrade);

    for ( i = 0 ; i < NumOfGrade ; i ++ ) {

        printf("\nenter the grade\n");
        scanf("%d", &grade);

        totalGrade += grade ;

        if ( grade < 12 )
        failsCount ++;
    }

    ave = (float) totalGrade / NumOfGrade ;

    printf("the ave of ur grade are  : \n");
    printf("%.2f\n", ave);
    printf("%d subj fails\n", failsCount);

    printf("do you want to startover ? (Y or N) \n");
    __fpurge(stdin); // clear your input buffer, on window, try fflush(stdin)
    ans = getchar();
    if ( ans == 'Y') 
        goto loop1 ;
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, and is just as likely to do nothing or terminate the program.

Comment: don't flush stdin like that, prefer some stupid thing like `while ((c=getchar)=='\n');`